# Update with Many to Many relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I have an Entity Object `Item` :

```
public partial class Item : Entity 
{
    public int   ItemId { get; set; }
    ....
    public virtual IList<ItemStandard> Standards { get; set; }

}
```

and I have `ItemStandard` , `Itemstandard`'s can belong to many `Item`'s and `Item`'s can have many `ItemStandard`'s

```
public partial class ItemStandard : Entity
{
    public int ItemStandardId { get; set; }
    ....
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ItemStandardGroup ItemStandardGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I left out insignificant parts of these objects.  Here is my mapping:

```
public class ItemMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemMapping()
    {
        HasMany(t => t.Standards)
            .WithMany(t => t.Items)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("ItemStandardRelationShip");
                m.MapLeftKey("ItemId");
                m.MapRightKey("ItemStandardId");
            });
    }
}
```

When I do retrieve an object from the context if work fine -  If I do

```
  context.Item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == whatever);
```

it will return all the `ItemStandard`'s in the Property Standards like it is suppose to.

Now , I try to do an update like this:

```
    public Item SaveItem(Item item, int[] Standards)
    {          
        foreach (var a in Standards)
        {
            var newStandard = _context.ItemStandard.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemStandardId == a);
                item.Standards.Add(newStandard);

        }
        _context.Item.Attach(item);
        _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return _context.Item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == item.ItemId);
    }
```

You can see how instead of returning the object that I saved , I actually call another `SELECT` from the database to ensure that the save happened.  When I stop this in the debugger I see everything working correctly.  The New `ItemStandard`'s are attached to the Item , and if I go into each `ItemStandard` there is now a new `Item` Property of the new item.

When I go into the database afterwards though , nothing has been changed in my ItemStandardRelationShip table.  It's like nothing happened. The context is setup just fine , everything else in every repository works correctly.   Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out, i guess,that all the tutorials I read were wrong.  You have to actually set the changes in both objects that are affected

```
     foreach (var a in Standards)
    {
        var newStandard = _context.ItemStandard.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemStandardId == a);
        newStandard.Items.Add(item);
            item.Standards.Add(newStandard);

    }
```